# Android image upload : broken pipe

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, image-upload

I'm uploading images (one at a time) from an android application (using retrofit2 and okhttp3) to a springboot server. I'm using base64 to convert the image file to a string. I got it working for one image on my phone but it won't work for any other images.

Android code:

```
try {
     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
     String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     baos.flush();
     baos.close();
     Log.d(TAG, base64Image);
     beconnect.uploadPhoto(base64Image, "imagename");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
     System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
}

@POST("/uploadImage")
@FormUrlEncoded
<Observable<retrofit2.Response<String>> uploadPhoto(@Field("image") String image, @Field("name") String name);//@Part("desc") RequestBody desc, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

This is the original post for the image that works...
POST http://192.168.1.11:8080/uploadImage http/1.1 (393608-byte body)

This is the post that fails...
POST http://192.168.1.11:8080/uploadImage http/1.1 (11115982-byte body)

**Error:**

> HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe at
>   okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1Codec.java:286) at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:63)
>   ....

I'm aware that the byte sizes vary between the two images...is this the cause of the issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did your server print any exceptions to the log? A broken pipe means the socket connection was terminated by the server before it completed successfully.

Comment: `aware that the byte sizes vary between the two images...is this the cause of the issue and how do I fix it?` Then send the second image first. Or only the second one.

Comment: `(11115982-byte body)` Pretty bad code to put so much bytes in memory before posting. It already is a bad idea to use base64 encoding as you augment the amount of bytes with 30% doing so.

Comment: `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);` Bad too. Why are you constructing a bitmap from a file first? Upload the bytes of the file directly.

Comment: @greenapps what should I use instead

Comment: Repeat: `Upload the bytes of the file directly. `. Depending on your server. If your server expects base64 you are out of luck.

Comment: @MattClark no, the server hasn't printed any exceptions to the log...